# ¿En qué lenguaje está hecho Stack Overflow?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange

Solo por curiosidad, me gustaría saber en qué lenguaje de programación esta hecha esta pagina (Stack Overflow).

Echando un vistazo con CTRL+U solo veo algunos `<script>` y tampoco veo `.php` o `.aspx` en las urls. Imagino que el lenguaje que se utilizó debe ser bastante óptimo para ser una plataforma de ayuda a los programadores.

Comment: Basicamente, C#. [Aqui explican exactamente las tecnologías usadas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Comment: @Pikoh gracias!

Comment: Aquí una serie de artículos bastente interesantes (en inglés): [Stack Overflow: A Technical Deconstruction](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/03/stack-overflow-a-technical-deconstruction/).